# Self-contained python installation with executable tools included (pip, orbited, etc)

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying deploy a Python application on Windows as a folder that includes a full python 2.6 folder. I don't need/want a fancy solution like py2exe, I'm just trying to automate deployment of a web application.

So long as I include python26.dll and set the PYTHONHOME correctly, things seem to work if I just include the Python26 folder in its entirety.  However a number of the Python26/Script files don't work. For instance, pip.exe, orbited.exe, and morbid.exe all do nothing (complete with no output) when I try to run them on a system that doesn't have a real Python26 installation.

I've run out of ideas.  Suggestions?

Comment: IMHO, using py2exe would give you a much smaller cleaner build, since it selects only the modules that are used in your code.

If you need a full Python install, you're gonna need the Registry and environment variables (like PATH) that the Python installer would include. Maybe you could do a quiet default install of Python?

Answer (score 1):

How about trying to use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv/1.4.8)?